# Nexus 3 Compact blob store task does not remove images physically

Tags: nexus, nexus3

We were deleting old docker images with keeping last 10 of them. We tried Compact blob store task to delete them physically but on the administration/Repository settings, Blob store still shows the same size after deleting images.

This is the compact blob store log:

```
2018-06-28 14:18:40,709+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.compact.internal.CompactBlobStoreTask - Task information:
2018-06-28 14:18:40,712+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.compact.internal.CompactBlobStoreTask -  ID: 2bf9a574-f3e6-4f8e-8351-d98e4abc5103
2018-06-28 14:18:40,712+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.compact.internal.CompactBlobStoreTask -  Type: blobstore.compact
2018-06-28 14:18:40,712+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.compact.internal.CompactBlobStoreTask -  Name: cbs
2018-06-28 14:18:40,712+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.compact.internal.CompactBlobStoreTask -  Description: Compacting default blob store
2018-06-28 14:18:40,713+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.file.FileBlobStore - Deletions index file rebuild not required
2018-06-28 14:18:40,713+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.file.FileBlobStore - Begin deleted blobs processing
2018-06-28 14:18:41,551+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.file.FileBlobStore - Elapsed time: 837.6 ms, processed: 45/45
2018-06-28 14:18:41,551+0200 INFO  [quartz-6-thread-20]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.compact.internal.CompactBlobStoreTask - Task complete
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker layers can be shared across many different images, so the layers associated with an image are not deleted automatically when you delete an image. First run a "docker - delete unused manifests and images" task, then try running the compact blobstore again.

Comment: Running "docker delete unused manifests and images" task and then, compact blob task handled it well.